# Setting vector of shared_ptr - _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse error

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to port [Catalin Zima's 2D skeletal animation](http://www.catalinzima.com/2011/06/2d-skeletal-animations/) sample in C# to C++ in order to learn C++.

I am encountering a strange error with updating a vector of shared_ptr that I assume is memory related as I only encounter this error after three iterations of the code.

_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)

In my code, I used a class named Transformation, which contains data about 2D transformations, like translation, rotation and scale. Then, a Keyframe is defined by a frame number and one such Transformation. A collection of Keyframes defines a KeyframeAnimation. Finally, a SkeletonAnimation is a collection of KeyframeAnimations, one for each bone in the skeleton.

On my Skeleton class I have a vector of type Transformation `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Transform>> _localTransforms;`. The idea is this is set from the SkeletonAnimationPlayer which first updates the Transformations for the current animation and then sets the Transformation onto the Skeleton via a Apply method on the player.

```
//SkeletonAnimationPlayer
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<KeyFrameAnimationState>> _jointAnimations;

void SkeletonAnimationPlayer::Update(float elapsedSeconds)
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < _jointAnimations.size(); i++)
    {
        _jointAnimations[i]->Update(elapsedSeconds);
    }
}

void SkeletonAnimationPlayer::Apply(Skeleton& skeleton)
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < _jointAnimations.size(); i++)
    {
         skeleton.SetLocalTransform(i, *_jointAnimations[i]->CurrentKeyFrame);
    }
}

//Skeleton
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Transformation>> _localTransforms;

void Skeleton::SetLocalTransform(int jointIndex, Transformation& transform)
{
    //When debugging this line seems to cause the error
    _localTransforms[jointIndex] = std::shared_ptr<Transformation>(&transform);
}

//Main
_animationPlayer->Update(deltaTime);
_animationPlayer->Apply(*_skeleton.get());
```

However after three iterations of the main loop (the third time I call Apply) I receive the following error:

_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)

My question is two part. Am I doing this correcty? What does this error mean and why am I receiving it?

I've tried resetting the smart_ptr on SetLocalTransform but still receive the same error:

```
_localTransforms[jointIndex].reset(&transform);
```